# Is there an possible way to implement compact IF-statements in my python code?

Tags: python, if-statement

Currently I have 3 If-statements done like this:

```
if filetype not in filetypes:
     print(f'  SKIPPED - WRONG FILETYPE: {filetype}')
     continue
elif 'comments' in meme_url or 'gallery' in meme_url:
     print('  SKIPPED - NOT A MEME')
     continue
elif meme_id in memes or meme_id in used_memes:
     print('  SKIPPED - USED')
     continue
```

These are sorting out non-valid images and I want to be able to traceback which 'filter' worked (currently it's done via print('problem')).

Nevertheless, this code 'smells' bad, so I am interested in more intelligent solution, if there is one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: They all work on (filter based upon) different criteria. Even if you put them in separate functions, you are going to have functions with extraneous args.

Comment: What is bad about this code? You have 3 independent conditions, so you have 3 checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def filter_by_name(filename, meme_url, used_memes):
    '''
    Returns True if filtered IN for more processing. False, if filtered out.
    '''

filters = [filter_by_name, filter_by_comment, filter_by_id]

filtered_out = False
for filter_function in filters:
    if not filter_function(filename, meme_url, used_memes):
        print(f'Not selected because did not pass through {filter_function}')
        filtered_out = True
        break
  
if filtered_out:
    continue
# Passed though all filters so process more
```

But as mentioned in comment, you are going to have function which have args which they don't even use.